# Timezone offset with NY / Europe?

Tags: php, timezone-offset

Why is New York showing a difference of 10 hours from UTC for the following code ?

Here is my Query :

```
    $my_timezone = new DateTimeZone("Europe/London");
    $server_timezone = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");

    $my_date = new DateTime("now", $my_timezone);
    $server_date = new DateTime("now", $server_timezone);

    $my_offset = $my_timezone->getOffset($my_date);
    $server_offset = $server_timezone->getOffset($server_date);

    echo "[my: $my_offset][srv: $server_offset]";
```

Comment: I get `+1` for `$my_offset` (3600 seconds), and `-4` for `$server_offset` (-14400 seconds), which is correct...

Comment: Same here: http://3v4l.org/ekXsu

Comment: Doh! I wasn't doing 60 x 60 I was doing 14400 / 60 / 24!! That will be the minutes I needed! Thanks for pointing it out.